# CSS Grid, Horizontal Spacing of Columns: min-content does not seem to do what I expect

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I've been reading and reading and I'm still stuck understanding how and why min-content seems to fail me in this example.

I have the following HTML (snipped from one project and simplified to the point of a good example):

```html
<div class="lo_buttons">
        <div class="lo_reload_icon">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-application-icons/24/Apply.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        </div>

        <div class="lo_reload">
            <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btnReload">
                <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/c9d/go.png" class="img_button">
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="lo_shortcuts">
          <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn3">3</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn4">4</button>
    </div>

        <div class="lo_space">
        </div>

        <div class="lo_utils">
          <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn3">3</button>
        </div>  
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```css
.lo_buttons {
    grid-area: lo_buttons; 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content;
    grid-auto-rows: min-content min-content min-content 1fr min-content;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-areas: "lo_reload lo_reload_icon lo_shortcuts lo_space lo_utils";
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}

.lo_reload      { grid-area: lo_reload; }
.lo_reload_icon { grid-area: lo_reload_icon;  }
.lo_shortcuts   { grid-area: lo_shortcuts; }
.lo_utils       { grid-area: lo_utils;  }
.lo_space       { grid-area: lo_space; }

.button_left { 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button_right { 
    float: right; 
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

which is all on codepen at:

https://codepen.io/bernd-wechner/pen/NWPwOXP

(where I can play with it)

The puzzle I have is that I'd like group of buttons number 1 2 3 4 snug against the tick icon to its left. The div the icon is in, is min-content yet consumes far more space than the icon in it. What am I missing here? And why does min-content not keep that grid cell as wide asd the icon in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `grid-auto-rows` where it should be `grid-template-columns` and it should be `max-content` not `min-content` since `min-content` will get the minimum width considering line-break and I suppose you want the button to remain on the same row.

```css
.lo_buttons {
 grid-area: lo_buttons; 
 display: grid;
 grid-auto-columns: min-content; /* maybe auto-columns here ?*/
 grid-template-columns: max-content max-content max-content 1fr max-content;
 grid-column-gap: 5px;
 grid-template-areas: "lo_reload lo_reload_icon lo_shortcuts lo_space lo_utils";
 /*white-space: nowrap !important; useless*/
}

.lo_reload      { grid-area: lo_reload; }
.lo_reload_icon { grid-area: lo_reload_icon;  }
.lo_shortcuts   { grid-area: lo_shortcuts; }
.lo_utils       { grid-area: lo_utils;  }
.lo_space       { grid-area: lo_space; }

.button_left { 
 float: left; 
 margin-right: 0.5em;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button_right { 
 float: right; 
 margin-left: 0.5em;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lo_buttons">
  <div class="lo_reload_icon">
   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-application-icons/24/Apply.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">
  </div>
  
  <div class="lo_reload">
   <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btnReload">
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/c9d/go.png" class="img_button">
   </button>
  </div>
   
  <div class="lo_shortcuts">
    <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn3">3</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn4">4</button>
    </div>
   
  <div class="lo_space">
  </div>

  <div class="lo_utils">
    <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn3">3</button>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

I see you were also trying to use `white-space:nowrap` but it will only work if you remove `float` and in this case you can keep `min-content` because it will give you the same result as `max-content` since we disabled the line break

```css
.lo_buttons {
 grid-area: lo_buttons; 
 display: grid;
 grid-auto-columns: min-content; /* maybe auto-columns here ?*/
 grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content 1fr min-content;
 grid-column-gap: 5px;
 grid-template-areas: "lo_reload lo_reload_icon lo_shortcuts lo_space lo_utils";
 white-space: nowrap ;
}

.lo_reload      { grid-area: lo_reload; }
.lo_reload_icon { grid-area: lo_reload_icon;  }
.lo_shortcuts   { grid-area: lo_shortcuts; }
.lo_utils       { grid-area: lo_utils;  }
.lo_space       { grid-area: lo_space; }

.button_left { 
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button_right { 
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lo_buttons">
  <div class="lo_reload_icon">
   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-application-icons/24/Apply.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">
  </div>
  
  <div class="lo_reload">
   <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btnReload">
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/c9d/go.png" class="img_button">
   </button>
  </div>
   
  <div class="lo_shortcuts">
    <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn3">3</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_left" id="btn4">4</button>
    </div>
   
  <div class="lo_space">
  </div>

  <div class="lo_utils">
    <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_right" id="btn3">3</button>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Admit that CSS has so many options it's hard at times to see straight through them all. But your examples are elegant, clarifying and well appreciated. Both approaches work wonderfully.